# Fmod constans (FMOD_HARDWARE) not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fmod

I am using FMOD in Ubuntu to play sound in my game.

I have the next

```
#include "SoundEngine.h"
bool SoundEngine::initSystem()
{
  System_Create(&system);// create an instance of the game engine
system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);// initialise the game engine with 32 channels


//load sounds
system->createSound("Media/NoMoreMagic.ogg", FMOD_HARDWARE, 0, &sound1);
sound1->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_OFF);    /* drumloop.wav has embedded loop points which automatically makes looping turn on, */

/* so turn it off here.  We could have also just put FMOD_LOOP_OFF in the above CreateSound call. */
system->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, sound1, false, 0);
return true;

}
```

And the SoundEngine.h is:

```
#ifndef SOUNDENGINE_H_
#define SOUNDENGINE_H_

#include "FMOD/inc/fmod.hpp" //fmod c++ header
#pragma comment( lib, "fmodex_vc.lib" ) // fmod library

using namespace FMOD;
class SoundEngine{
public:
    bool initSystem(void);
private:
//FMod Stuff
    System     *system; //handle to FMOD engine
    Sound      *sound1, *sound2; //sound that will be loaded and played
};  



#endif /* SOUNDENGINE_H_ */
```

THe problem is that FMOD_HARDWARE or FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE is not found.

Anyone knows where are they?

EDIT: Another thing is that the pragma comment throws a warning telling that ignore pragma. Maybe the problem has relation with the pragma? How can I fix the pragma?

Comment: `#pragma comment` to link a library is a Microsoft Visual C++ extension. Also, you're trying to link with a `.lib` file, which is usually a Windows library, On POSIX systems (such as Ubuntu) static library files end in `.a`.

Comment: I am using Eclipse so I only need to go to Preferences and put it in Libraries in the menu Path and Symbols right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe FMOD_HARDWARE is from the older FMOD Ex API. Are you using FMOD 5? In my calls to System::createSound I use FMOD_DEFAULT or FMOD_CREATESAMPLE (the latter will load the entire sound and decompress it in memory, to speed up playback) which seems to use the hardware well. For your playSound call, try

```
FMOD::Channel *channel;
system->playSound(sound1, NULL, false, &channel);
```